# Google Analytics _trackEvent - always root of site

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-analytics

I am trying to do some quite strange stuff with Google Analytics, I will try and explain as best as possible.

I have a holding site, that loads a form in via jQuery, the main site has its own tracking code, and the ajax loaded content using a different tracking code, this works fine.

```
_gat._createTracker('UA-XXXXXXXX-2', 'myTracker');
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['myTracker._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-2']);
```

The form is broken up into multiple parts and I push a page track event with a custom page url through as each part is completed, again this seems to work fine.

```
_gaq.push(['myTracker._trackPageview', '/form/stage1/']);
```

But what I want to do is track events for changes in the form (dropdown changes, etc...), this is kinda working, the events as visible in the Google Analytics interface, but in the pages tab, they all appear under "/" not "/form/stage1/" as I would like (I think that the "/" is coming from the main site which it is sat in.

```
_gaq.push(['myTracker._trackEvent', 'Sample', ddValue]);
```

So what I am asking is there any way to tell _trackEvent to track against a different page url?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is not; `_trackEvent` uses `location.pathname+location.search`, regardless of what the most recent `_trackPageview` call passed as its custom value.

However, you're only use the "Category" and "Action" fields of the Event; you still have the "Label" to which you can pass that value in.

```
_gaq.push(['myTracker._trackEvent', 'Sample', ddValue, "/form/stage/1"]);
```